# How can I create a PowerShell function with a dynamic number of parameters, each of which will be passed to another command?

Tags: command-line, powershell, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Title is pretty much self-explanatory. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function Git {
    $cmd = $args[0]
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $args.count; $i++) {
        $cmd = $cmd + " " + $args[$i]
    }
    echo $(wsl git $cmd)
}
```

Yet calling e.g. `git clone <clone URL>` gives me `git: 'clone <clone URL>' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` So it seems as though PowerShell is passing a quoted string to the `git` command, and that is causing it to fail...**or is there some other issue with my code that I'm missing?**

That's hopefully enough info for any PowerShell expert to point me in the right direction...although to understand my actual core problem and what I've done to try to fix it, please read on...

#### Core Problem/Existing Solutions

I am trying to redirect all `git` commands typed within a PowerShell or CMD window to WSL, as that is the only place where I have `git` installed **and I'd like to keep it that way**. I see no sense in installing Git for Windows or any other large third-party tools when I have everything that I need already installed in WSL.

The only downsides to that are:

1. Typing `wsl git...` every time I want to clone, pull, push etc. gets cumbersome and tiring *very quickly* for someone who types such commands many times per day.
2. It also breaks the Git extension in my Windows VS Code installation to not have Git for Windows installed.

I have tried two existing solutions to these problems, namely https://github.com/hangxingliu/wslgit and https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit, but both of them give me the same error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Kenny> git --version
/usr/bin/wslgit.sh: line 83: cd: C:\Users\Kenny: No such file or directory
fatal: can not cd to C:\Users\Kenny (C:\Users\Kenny)
```

See also [this seemingly-related GitHub issue](https://github.com/hangxingliu/wslgit/issues/17) in the former repo for more information.

I am running Windows 10.0.19042.0, i.e. the latest stable build of Windows 10 Home. There must have been some breaking change in this or the previous release, since the former repo's owner references this in their comments on the linked issue page:

> I have updated wslgit.dev.sh a little.
> First of all `mount -t drvfs` => return nothing to, it happened after update to 2004.
> So I have updated wslgit.dev.sh file...And now it works for me. After that, generate new `wslgit.sh` and change old one.

I have tried their suggestion, but it didn't seem to help the situation for either me or the OP of the issue. Hence me going down the whole rabbit hole of writing a custom PowerShell function to achieve a similar result.

I've now wasted an entire day on trying to solve this seemingly-simple problem (the entire morning on trying to get the existing solutions working, and the rest of the day on the PowerShell workaround). I would therefore very much appreciate either:

1. An explanation of, and fix for, the error message given to me by both existing solutions, or
2. A working PowerShell function that does what I want, without having to add verbose parameter names or anything else to an already-too-long command (IMO).

Comment: Why not create a batch file `GIT.BAT` with content `WSL GIT %*` and placing it in your PATH? PowerShell will happily invoke CMD to execute batch files.

Comment: `echo $(wsl git $args)` as the function body seems to work for me, at least for the simple clone case you mentioned (and a simple `Git status`.  It's still going to fail in a number of use cases, including-but-probably-not-limited-to any git command needing user input, using a local Windows path as a target, being on a UNC path (including \\WSL$\) when executing the command, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yeah I don't expect complex Git commands to work, especially the types you mentioned. But 99% of my daily Git needs are `add .`, `commit -m <message>`, `pull`, `push` and `status`. Then I might occasionally need `clone <clone URL>`, but will always be in the desired root folder beforehand. So I can't see myself needing much beyond what you've suggested, nor can I believe how incredibly simple the solution turned out to be! If you write up your comment as a proper answer, I'll gladly accept it since you most certainly deserve the rep! TYVM :D

Comment: Excellent - Great to hear that will work for your use case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `args` array directly seems to work for me, as in:

```
function Git {
    echo $(wsl git $args)
}
```

at least for the simple clone case you mentioned (and a simple `Git status`).

While it sounds like that's mostly what you need, future readers should be aware that this will likely fail for more complex use-cases such as any git command needing user input, using a local Windows path as a target, or being on a UNC path (including `\\WSL$\`) when executing it.